Divs with images won't scale on mobile
Working on building a responsive site and I've gotten all my divs to fit mobile other than the divs that contain images. Those are bigger and create an overhang.
The picture shows the issue on #welcome-pic.#welcome-pic
And here it is on an image in a book-pick div.
book-pick
@media screen and (max-width:650px){
    .col{ 
        width:90%; 
        object-fit: contain;
    }

    .book-pick img{ 
        width: 70%; 
        object-fit: contain;
    }

    #welcome-pic{ 
        width:70%; 
        object-fit: contain; 
    }

.col2{ 
    width:100%
} }

I added the 'col' class to every div that contains an image. I added the next two rules that should apply to those images as well, in case specificity was the issue.
Here is the site: translatedokc.com
Here is the HTML for the welcome image:
<section>
            <div class="gen-container">
                <div class="col"><img src="images/welcome-pic.jpg" id="welcome-pic" alt="A book club meeting at Bookish"></div>
                <div class="box2">
                    <h1 class="textbox" class="col">Welcome to OKC's Translated Fiction    Book Club!</h1>
                    <p class="textbox" class="col">We are an Oklahoma City-based book club that focuses on fiction in translation. Our meetings take place every 2nd Thursday at Bookish: Used Books & Art.</p>
                    <p class="textbox" class="col">
                        Follow us on <a href="https://www.instagram.com/translatedokc/" target="_blank">Instagram</a><br>
                        or join us on <a href="https://app.thestorygraph.com/book_clubs/e7f8bd89-3b60-42bd-b43d-d1ff59411abb" target="_blank">the Storygraph</a>
                    </p>
                 </div>
                <div class="textbox" id="faq-box" class="col">
                    <h4> Frequently Asked Questions</h4>
                    <div>
                        <p><b>When and where does book club take place?</b></p>
                        <p>We meet every second Thursday at 7pm at Bookish in Oklahoma City.<br><i>1005 NW 36th Street</i><br>By Western, near Guestroom Records and Cock O' the Walk.</p>
                        <p><b>Do I need to attend every meeting?</b></p>
                        <p>Nope! Just come to any meeting. We don’t keep attendance. We appreciate your participation and your company, whether you only join us once or become a frequent member.</p>
                        <p><b>What if I don’t finish the book?</b></p>
                        <p>You’re welcome to join us whether you’ve finished our book pick or not, as long as you’re OK with spoilers being discussed.</p>
                        <p><b>Do I need to buy the books from Bookish?</b></p>
                        <p>You can join us no matter how you acquire the book.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


The following CSS will make your images adjust to the full width of their parent elements:
.book-pick img,
#welcome-pic img,
.col img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

Then I removed this from your current CSS:
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    #welcome-pic {
        width: 70%; 
        object-fit: contain; 
    }
}


Edit
Updated answer after getting access to repo for reproduction.
#welcome-pic {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#gen-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #d6d1b1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .col {
    width: 90%;
  }

  .col2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}





I made this change but sadly it did not work. The problem persists on mobile.

What does max-width: 100 do?
